# Email validation on Registration and checkout page on magento 2

Tags: magento2

At registration and checkout page there is bug related to email validation like if you enter

> john@mail.test.com

in email field then magento will accept such wrong email format.
Actually magento doesn't verify domain format.

Anybody knows how can we fix it?

Thank you,
Vijay

Comment: Anybody knows, how can we fix this.

Comment: Replace regular expression for email validation field and in core Magento as well...

Comment: I don't use magento, but you can write your own JS validation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for above bug.

We can override following file in theme

> lib/web/mage/validation.js

Theme path:

> app/design/frontend/'Magento/luma'/web/mage/validation.js

There find the rule: 'validate-email':  and then replace

> function (v) {
> return $.mage.isEmptyNoTrim(v) || /^([a-z0-9,!#$%&'*+/=?^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`{|}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*@([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(.([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*.(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]){2,})$/i.test(v); //eslint-disable-line max-len
> },

To

function (v) {
return $.mage.isEmptyNoTrim(v) || /^([a-z0-9,!#$%&'*+/=?^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`{|}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*@([a-z0-9]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(.([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(!.))*.(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]){2,})$/i.test(v); //eslint-disable-line max-len
},

There we have added (!.) "not .(dot)"

Thank you